# Capture form text from HTML in JS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So I have the following code:

```html
<div align="left" id="operationInformation" style="display:none;">
  <p class="operation-details">You chose operation: {{operationDetails.returnType}} <span id="operation-details-name">{{operationDetails.name}}</span></p>

  <div ng-repeat="parameter in operationDetails.parameters">
    <p></p>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Parameter$index</label>
      <p class="operation-details">{{parameter.type}} <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="{{parameter.name}}"></p>
    </form>
    <p></p>

  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Basically it is just a a series of forms and a Submit button.

Please see picture below for clarification: 
[image]

When I type "true" inside the form, I want that when I click "Submit" I'll get the value inserted in the form somehow captured in javascript, so that I can use it to call a controller with the inserted parameter.

I use Angular 1.6.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please add more code, a working snippet will be  very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jquery val() method to retrieve the value.

```
var x = $('#inlineFormInput').val();
```

Just call a function on the onsubmit event of the form and put this logic there.

Otherwise you could use the [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method of jquery.